# django: how to correctly specify output-download file-type (in this case mp3)?

Tags: django, text-to-speech

I have a simple django platform where I can upload text files. Ultimately I want to return a downloadable mp3 audio file made from the text in the uploaded file. My problem currently is that I cannot seem to correctly specify the type of file that the website outputs for download.

I then tried to make the downloadable output of the website an mp3 file:

views.py (code adapted from https://github.com/sibtc/simple-file-upload)

```
def simple_upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
    myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
    print(str(request.FILES['myfile']))
    x=str(myfile.read())
    tts = gTTS(text=x, lang='en')
    response=HttpResponse(tts.save("result.mp3"),content_type='mp3')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=result.mp3'
    return response
return render(request, 'core/simple_upload.html')
```

Upon pressing the upload button, the text-to-speech conversion is successful but the `content_type` of the response is not definable as 'mp3'. The file that results from the download is `result.mp3.txt` and it contains 'None'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems I can see here. The first is that `tts.save()` returns `None`, and that is getting passed directly to the `HttpResponse`. Secondly, the `content_type` is set to `mp3` and ought to be set to `audio/mp3`.

After calling `tts.save()`, open the mp3 and pass the file handle to the `HttpResponse`, and then also set the `content_type` correctly - for example:

```
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        ...
        tts.save("result.mp3")
        response=HttpResponse(open("result.mp3", "rb"), content_type='audio/mp3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to prepare your response using the sample code below?

I've managed to return CSV files correctly this way so it might help you too.

Here it is:

```
HttpResponse(content_type='text/plain')  # Plain text file type
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="attachment.txt"'  # Plain text file extension
response.write("Hello, this is the file contents.")
return response
```

Comment: Hi I used you code for the text example and it works. However when I try to apply this to the mp3 case, the resulting mp3 file is a text file containing 'None'...

        `x=str(myfile.read()); 
        tts = gTTS(text=x, lang='en'); 
        response=HttpResponse(tts.save("eg.mp3"),content_type='mp3'); 
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=result.mp3';
        return response`

Comment: in the above piece of code, `eg.mp3` should be `result.mp3`- this has been corrected in my code